Missing permission to access internal storage
Via Settings > Apps > Fayr > Permissions, I can set various permissions for the Android app Fayr (i.e., Calendar, Camera, Contacts, Location, Notifications), and all of them have been set to permission granted. However, the one permission that the app actually requires to work properly is not even visible and, thus, cannot be granted: 'Files and media'. Whenever I start Fayr, I receive the information "Error! To access files or photos, enable access to local storage".
Through third-party permission manager apps (e.g., App Permission Manager or Permissions Manager Dashboard), I can see that the permission 'Files and media' is listed for Fayr, yet these apps cannot activate that permission either.
What is the correct way to solve this issue?
(My Android info: One UI version: 6.0, Android version: 14)

You can try Permission Manager to enable. If root is not available, you would need to grant it elevated privileges using adb

App is developed by an esteemed contributor on this site  Irfan // Tg link

Is this the app? If so, then I'm afraid Android 14 breaks the app due to partial access to photos and videos, which the developer has to fix. I checked it on Android 13 and the storage permission is deliberately ignored by the system, which looks similar to a reported issue about the Imgur app on Android 13.

@AndrewT. Yes, that is the app. Unfortunately, the app developer has not responded to my support requests for weeks. I suspect that they are struggling to update/fix their own app.

@AndrewT. Do I need to conclude that I would need to downgrade to Android 13 to make this app work until the developer has fixed the issue (whenever that may be)?

@MichaelGruenstaeudl on the contrary, I'm afraid it won't work on Android 13 either with fresh app installation. There's an official explanation in the case of upgrading Android version when the storage permission will be preserved, but not sure for fresh installation. Unfortunately, I can't proceed with the app further because it needs to log in. I also checked the reviews in the Play Store, but looks like there were not so much reviews, and no info about Android 13/14 compatibility...
